# Logic to get delta changes

Tags: python, pyspark, logic, azure-cosmosdb

I have an asset used in different organization.

I am trying to get how may hours asset used in a org for a given day.

Consider hours as total kilometers ran in a vehicle. It will keep increment.

I have an job which will get hours of an asset present in org every hour.

SampleData snapshot asset with same org:

[image]

In this case, asset is used only in one org so it will be easy to get hours for a day.

```
MaxHours(8) - MinHours(2) = 6 hours a day
```

But, If asset is used in multiple org in same day. I will have data like below.

Here, i sorted by time desc.

SampleData snapshot asset with multiple org

[image]

If i do group by asset and org and get min and max value. Will have data like below.

GroupBy org and asset

[image]

But now i can not do max and min.

Eg.: org 1

```
MaxHour(22) - MinHours(10) = 12 hours a day
```

Which is wrong.

At first, org 1 used asset 'A' for 4 hours and asset moved to org 2.
and later in that day asset moved back to org 1 for 2 hours.

So total should be 6 hours.

Based on second snapshot it should be.

```
14 - 10 = 4

22 - 20 = 2

Total: 6 hours
```

I am not able to find when asset moved to different org.
and not getting logic to perform above computation.

Note that i can't use for loop as i have more than 900k records/rows for a day.

I am doing it in Databrick(Python Spark) connecting to CosmosDB.

Comment: what is the expected delta changes for Org 2 and Org 3? if both are 4, then you just need to calculate lag('Hours') over a window function and then groupby and take the sum.

Comment: Thank you jxc, 
But problem with first row If i do lag('Hours') then first record of lag column will be zero.

Comment: the first delta_hour is null, I think that's expected. If you need the final result of Org 2 = 2 and Org 3 = 4, then you might need another window to set up the first one in a group with one more rows of Org + Asset combo shown in consecutive hours which should has delta_hour = 0. otherwise the `deala_hours = hours - prev_hours`

Comment: Org 2 and Org 3 has to be 4. I am trying to add another window. Thank you jxc.

Comment: if both Org-2 and Org-3 are 4, you probably just need one Window, for example: df.withColumn('delta_hours', F.col('Hours') - F.lag('Hours').over(Window.partitionBy('Asset').orderBy('Hours'))).groupby('Org', 'Asset').agg(F.sum('delta_hours'))

Comment: Yes, This will work. Thank you.

Comment: @RaviTeja If you are not blocked by this anymore, please summarize your findings as an answer below so it can help others in the community who might have similar questions. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for late reply, yes @jxc answer helped me to solve the problem using lag.